Apache ECharts: making plot start from 0 when using slider
I'm trying to use the Apache Echarts.  I have 2 functions and when I use the slider, I'd like that the data would be changed so that they start from 0 on the y-axis, just by shifting down.  This is a common case if you plot cummulatives in time of anything, and you want to use the slider to zoom in a particular timeframe.  Is functionality for this implemented?
thanks
I haven't seen this functionality in the documentation, but I'm probably missing it

It is not clear to me what you want to happen after moving the slider. Pls add a code example, images or  a more detailed description to clarify. Generally, you can listen to the dataZoom event and apply changes to your data based on that.
